# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send on remote server

Tags: c#, json, rest, ssl, https

When I try to call a REST service on a remote site with a https direction, I get the following error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Here's my code:

```
 public MyWebRequest(string url, string method, string data)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials(); // check below
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);


        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            delegate(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
                                    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
                                    System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            {
                return true; // **** Always accept
            };


        // -------------> The next line makes the error <------------------
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
        }



        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        string result = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Console.Write("Resultado: "+result);
    }
```

Also I have added the next instruction to disable the certificates validations of the https direction, but it didn't works...

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            delegate(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
                                    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
                                    System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            {
                return true;
            };
```

Comment: What does this have to do with VBA?  Or C# ?

Comment: I need it in C#, but if you have the solution in VBA, your welcome..